# why my program never reach the solve method?

Tags: java, inputstream

sorry if its a stupid question, but I a beginner using StreamTokenizer, I am trying to solve this exercise [this](http://acm.timus.ru/problem.aspx?space=1&num=1001), please help me, I dont know what its wrong in my program that never reach my solve method, it also never finishes, I already ask in timus forum, but I know that here is faster to receive an answers

```
import java.io.*;

public class Prueba {
    static int index = 0;
    static double[] l = new double[131072];

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        StreamTokenizer str = new StreamTokenizer(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)));
        while (((str.nextToken() != StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF))) {
            if (str.ttype == StreamTokenizer.TT_NUMBER) {
                l[index++] = str.nval;
                //System.out.println(str.nval);
                // System.out.println(l[0]);
                // System.out.println(l[1]);
            }
        }
        solve();
    }

    public static void solve() {
        double res;
        for (int i = index - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            res = Math.sqrt(l[i]);
            System.out.println(String.format("%.4f\n", res));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you step through your code in a debugger?  That would be the quickest way to identify where the problem is.

Comment: If you never reach the call to `solve()`, then your `while` loop must not be ending...

Comment: How are you running the program? Are you redirecting a file to standard input, or typing the input manually?

Comment: input manually so maybe it is the error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are reading from the standard input, and your code loops until it gets a `TT_EOF`. To feed a `TT_EOF` into your program, you need to press `Ctrl-D` if you're using Unix, or `Ctrl-Z` followed by `Enter` if you're using Windows.

Comment: It doesnt finish the loop, I just want to input until 16 MG then show the answers (solve method)

Comment: @GeorgeBecj: `break` out of the `while` as soon as `index` reaches 16.

Comment: I add the if(index>=16){break;} and the loop finishes, and also it shows the output from the solve method, thanks but I really can understand how to finish this loop

Comment: I already understand what the problem says it can have many numbers until end of file, so the judge will evaluate that

Answer (score 3):

You are waiting on System.in, it is blocking on read, ergo, you will never get to EOF so you while loop will continue to wait for input.

Comment: so how can I finish the loop?

Answer (score 1):

As it is, you either need to pipe a file from command line, or enter text on console followed by EOF character. Pressing Ctrl+Z generates EOF in Windows, and pressing Ctrl+D generates EOF in Unix/Linux.

**EDIT:** If your input is single line you can check for [TT_EOL](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/StreamTokenizer.html#TT_EOL) instead of TT_EOF.
You must call [eolIsSignificant(true)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/StreamTokenizer.html#eolIsSignificant%28boolean%29) before entering the loop. This will make sure end-of-line is treated as separate token

Comment: It doesnt finish the loop, I just want to input until 16 MG then show the answers